# Formato de data em python

Tags: python, datetime, data

Como pegar a data atual e formatar no formato brasileiro

```
'28/10/2019'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tente isso usando o datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

print(datetime.today().strftime('%d/%m/%Y'))
```

Comment: valeu, funcionou

Comment: @RubenBorgesRamos não escreva resolvido no titulo, basta marcar a resposta como correta, o site possui sistema para indicar o que é resolvido assim, não necessitas de uso "manual" como alterar titulos ;)

Comment: @RubenBorgesRamos fico feliz em ajudar  agr só marcar a resposta como correta 